# Export dashboard and chart into PDF (Apache Superset)

Tags: business-intelligence, apache-superset

New to Apache Superset. I am looking for functionality to export charts and dashboards to PDF.

I understand it can be exported as an image, but is the PDF possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible in Apache Superset 2.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I just download the image and convert the image to a PDF using my default PDF editing program. This seems to be the easiest and best solution.

Answer (score -2):

You can use "Export as PDF" option on Safari Browser.